# How to chose examples that fits within the context length per category from the csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a CSV file containing the following fields:

```
line_no,type,word_count
1,assertEquals,704
2,assertThat,303
3,assertNotNull,159
4,assertThat,348
5,assertFalse,186
6,assertArrayEquals,699
7,assertEquals,119
8,assertTrue,314
9,assertEquals,552
10,assertSame,151
11,assertEquals,110
12,assertEquals,210
13,assertTrue,807
14,assertTrue,1231
15,assertEquals,541
16,assertEquals,1435
17,assertEquals,305
18,assertEquals,134
19,assertArrayEquals,641
20,assertEquals,800
21,assertEquals,522
22,assertEquals,150
23,assertThat,608
24,assertArrayEquals,280
25,assertEquals,245
26,assertEquals,364
27,assertEquals,637
28,assertEquals,615
29,assertThat,362
30,assertTrue,1468
```

I have to return :

- **the line number of random examples having mean length from each category that fits within the context limit.**
- **Be equitable as possible as try to chose equal number of examples from each category.**

Looks like I have to take the following steps:

1. Find the mean length of `word_count` per each category.
2. Now filter out the csv and keep records only with the rows that has mean length per type
3. **Now loop over the categories in a round-robin fashion and one sample until it reaches the context length.**. Context length is 8000.

   - Need to put as many examples per category without exceeding context length.
   - Need to put example from all categories as much as possible in a round robin way.
   - So essentially return from the function is a list of all `line_no` that meets the average length for that type and does not exceed the 8000 context length.

**Output:**

Return a list of line numbers from each category.

My attempted code so far is implemented in the following snippet:

```
def avg_for_category(type:str):
    with open(file_name) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

        sum = 0
        num_rows = 0
        for row in reader:
            if row['type'] == type:
                word_count = int(row['word_count'])

                sum = sum + word_count
                num_rows = num_rows + 1

        word_count_average = sum / num_rows
        print(word_count_average)
        return word_count_average

# I am trying to get average in a hard coded way. 
# Probably there is a much better way as new types could be added.
assertEquals_avg =avg_for_category('assertEquals')
assertThat_avg =avg_for_category('assertEquals')
....
```

Firstly, for step 1 and 2 my code is quite hard coded for different categories and if new types are added, I have to change code. Is there a better way?

Also I am struggling to loop over the categories in a round-robin fashion and add one one sample at a time until it reaches the context length. Essentially I can address that in a hard-coded way as well i.e., making a dict of `type to line number` and iterating over and adding examples one by one.

But I am sure this is not the most appropriate way, and this code could be written in a terse and well-organized way.

Any pointers are welcome.

Comment: Do you have any code written yet? Or are you asking someone here to make it for you?

Comment: pasting code along with the question.

Comment: To make it dynamic, you'll have to iterate through the list `reader` first to grab all the `categories` into a list `categories` without allowing duplicates. then from that list `categories`, you can go through each `category`. This can get you your `word_count' average per category.

Answer (score 1):

Just groupby `type` and perform your operations.

1. Find the mean length of `word_count` per each category.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=file_name)

type_groupby = df.groupby("type")

average_word_count_by_type = type_groupby["word_count"].sum() / type_groupby.size()
```

```
type
assertArrayEquals    540.0000
assertEquals         465.1875
assertFalse          186.0000
assertNotNull        159.0000
assertSame           151.0000
assertThat           405.2500
assertTrue           955.0000
dtype: float64
```

2. Now filter out the csv and keep records only with the rows that has mean length per type.

```py
avg_word_count_df = df[
    average_word_count_by_type[df["type"]].values == df["word_count"]
]
```

```
   line_no           type  word_count
2        3  assertNotNull         159
4        5    assertFalse         186
9       10     assertSame         151
```

3. Now loop over the categories in a round-robin fashion and one sample until it reaches the context length. Context length is 8000.

```py
context_length = 8000

avg_length_line_nos = avg_word_count_df["line_no"].repeat(
    repeats=context_length // len(avg_word_count_df)
)
```

```
2     3
2     3
2     3
2     3
2     3
     ..
9    10
9    10
9    10
9    10
9    10
Name: line_no, Length: 7998, dtype: int64
```

Comment: very nice and eloquent, but does not address the step 3.

Comment: @Exploring `2. Now filter out the csv and keep records only with the rows that has mean length per type` are you sure you want to do this? You will end up filtering out most of the types. There is no row `assertEquals` in the csv whose `word_count` =  `465.1875`. You are pretty much just going to be left with types that have one entry in the csv.

Comment: the real CSV has 150K rows. This is just a sample.

Comment: Can step 3 be addressed using pandas?

Comment: @Exploring can you clarify what the result of step 3 looks like? I'm not sure I understand

Comment: clarified step-3 in details in the question.

Comment: @Exploring I'm guessing this is what you meant?

Comment: no - we need to take 1 sample at a time from each category until we hit the context length. Here we are taking from `avg_word_count_df["line_no"]` without considering the `type`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247109/discussion-between-ringo-and-exploring).